# How come deleting the setter method for the cards in my card game is not effecting to run it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm following the Stanford course and we created this first view controller for the game, and we created an `IBOutletCollection` of type `UIButton` to represent the cards.

Now, in the lecture he created a setter methods:

```
-(void) setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons {

    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
   [self updateUI];
}
```

And when I commented this method and tried to add more cards it work fine. Could you please kindly explain me why is that?

This is my CardGameViewController.m:

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardsDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"


@interface CardGameViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notificationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreCounter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (nonatomic) int flipsCount;

@end


@implementation CardGameViewController

//creating the getter method that creates a new card game.
-(CardMatchingGame *) game {

    if (!_game) _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:self.cardButtons.count usingDeck:[[PlayingCardsDeck alloc] init]];
    return _game;
}

//creating a setter for the IBOutletCollection cardButtons
-(void) setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons {

    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
   [self updateUI];
}


//creating the setter for the flipCount property. Whick is setting the flipsLabel to the right text and adding the number of counts.
-(void) setFlipsCount:(int)flipsCount {

    _flipsCount = flipsCount;
    self.flipsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d", self.flipsCount];

}


-(void) updateUI {

    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
        cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
        cardButton.enabled = !card.unplayble;
        if (card.unplayble) {
            cardButton.alpha = 0.1;
        }
        self.scoreCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];


        if (self.game.notification) {

        self.notificationLabel.text = self.game.notification;

        }

    }
}


//Here I created a method to flipCards when the card is selected, and give the user a random card from the deck each time he flips the card. After each flip i'm incrementing the flipCount setter by one.
- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
    self.flipsCount++;
    [self updateUI];
}


@end
```

Comment: The property defines the getter and setter methods. Defining your own simply replaces the synthesized one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties get default setter and getter methods.  You can override those methods yourself to add functionality (the `[self updateUI];` is such an example).

When you don't specify a setter or getter the default one is called instead.